# How do i display various div values using divs with the same id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok to start of i currently have 4 divs with the same id for example:

```
 <div id='name'></div>
 <div id='name'></div>
 <div id='name'></div>
 <div id='name'></div>
```

and im currently using a javascript function to display the value of the div's for example:

```
function divCheck(){
        alert(document.getElementById('name').innerHTML);
        }
```

the problem im having is when i call the function it only displays the value of the first div.

My goal is to display the values of all the divs and place it into a Textarea input.

I will really truly appreciate it. In advance thank you.

Comment: The ID's must be unique, instead use classes

Comment: An `id` attribute should be unique per page.

Comment: You **cannot** use the same id more than once.  This is not valid syntax.

Comment: @Sparky - you **can** use the same ID more than once. You are correct that it is not valid but browsers happily tolerate it, though the consequences are browser dependent and possibly not consistent.

Comment: @RobG:  Sure, by that logic, you can do just about anything you want and maybe it will still work.  Not sure what your point is.

Comment: My point is that you can use the same id multiple times, it won't freak out the browser or make your dog sick. It just means some scripting might not work as expected. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, use classes instead of ids.  Each id must be unique.  You cannot have more than one object with the same id.  Here's how it looks with a class name instead:

```
<div class='name'></div>
<div class='name'></div>
<div class='name'></div>
<div class='name'></div>
```

And, here's how you get all objects with a given class name and iterate over them:

```
function divCheck() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        alert(elems[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `getElementsByClassName()` was not supported by IE until IE9 so you will have to use a javascript shim that implements it a different way when it doesn't already exist.  Or, use a pre-built library like Sizzle or jQuery that already support this type of functionality in older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Use class instead of id, and use getElementsByClassName

ID is for use once, and is generally for large item (div etc) which has to be pretty unique, or is to be individually accessed, when you need to access combinations or even apply CSS properties on grpups of html elements without having to type them again and for each id, use class, and apply the common properties to that class, use ID for unique properties.

Similarly here use class, as you can see the function is get**Elements**ByClassName, means it returns a group, and this is what class is for. For this kind of use, use class instead of ID.

Answer (score 1):

Hey why don't you use the class instead of Ids. Give dynamic classNames like class="className-'+id+'"
And the call them using :

`$('div[class^="className-'+id+'""]')`
Hope it will be useful.

P.S Avoid using same ids for elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be after a getElementsByClassName function independant of any library, try the following. It tries *querySelectorAll* first, if not available it tries *getElementsByClassName*, and finally does an old school iterate over elements approach.

It will also accept multiple class names and always returns a static NodeList or array of the matched elements (per querySelectorAll). Note that getElemensByClassName returns a live NodeList, so the result must be converted to an array otherwise it might behave a little differently if elements are being added or removed from the document.

```
/*
  Selector must be per CSS period notation, using attribute notation
  (i.e. [class~=cName]) won't work for non qSA browsers:

    single class: .cName
    multiple class: .cName0.cName1.cName2

  If no root element provided, use document

  First tries querySelectorAll, 

  If not available replaces periods '.' with spaces
  and tries host getElementsByClassName

  If not available, splits on spaces, builds a RegExp
  for each class name, gets every element inside the
  root and tests for each class.

  Could remove duplicate class names for last method but
  unlikely to occur so probably a waste of time.

  Tested in:
    Firefox 5.0 (qSA, gEBCN, old)
    IE 8 (old method only, doesn't support qSA or gEBCN)
    Chrome 14 (qSA, gEBCN, old)
*/
function getByClassName(cName, root) {

  root = root || document;
  var reClasses = [], classMatch;
  var set = [], node, nodes;

  // Use qSA if available, returns a static list
  if (root.querySelectorAll) {
    return root.querySelectorAll(cName);
  }

  // Replace '.' in selector with spaces and trim
  // leading and trailing whitespace for following methods
  cName = cName.replace(/\./g, ' ').replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');

  // Use gEBCN if available
  if (root.getElementsByClassName) {
    nodes = root.getElementsByClassName(cName);

    // gEBCN usually returns a live list, make it static to be
    // consistent with other methods
    for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      set[i] = nodes[i];
    }
    return set;
  }

  // Do it the long way... trim leading space also
  nodes = root.getElementsByTagName('*');
  cName = cName.split(/\s+/);

  // Create a RegExp array of the class names to search on
  // Could filter for dupes but unlikely to be worth it
  for (var j = 0, jLen = cName.length; j < jLen; j++) {
    reClasses[j] = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName[j] + '\\s+|$');
  }

  // Test each element for each class name
  for (var m = 0, mLen = nodes.length; m < mLen; m++) {
    node = nodes[m];
    classMatch = true;

    // Stop testing class names when get a match
    for (var n = 0, nLen = reClasses.length; n < nLen && classMatch; n++) {
      classMatch = node.className && reClasses[n].test(node.className);
    }

    if (classMatch) {
      set.push(node);
    }
  }
  return set;
}
```